# How to get visible values by key event

Tags: jquery, html, keyevent

I am making a select box and putting the key event after keydown the scroller is not going down but the key event and selection of value is working well [image]

the fiddle is just working around it so how to control scroller
   http://jsfiddle.net/nsoni/d8FNp/1/

HTML:

```
<div class="scrol">
    <div class="ful ful_1">1</div>
    <div class="ful ful_2">2</div>
    <div class="ful ful_3">3</div>
    <div class="ful ful_4">4</div>
    <div class="ful ful_5">5</div>
    <div class="ful ful_6">6</div>
    <div class="ful ful_7">7</div>
    <div class="ful ful_8">8</div>
    <div class="ful ful_9">9</div>
    <div class="ful ful_10">10</div>
</div>
```

jquery:

```
var i=1;
$(window).bind('keydown', function(e){
    if (e.keyCode==13) {
        alert($('.change').text());
    } else if (e.keyCode==40) {
        if(i>=11)i=1;
        $('.ful').removeClass("change");
        $('.ful_'+i).addClass("change");  i++;     
    } 
     else if (e.keyCode==38) {
         if(i<=0)i=10;
         $('.ful').removeClass("change");
         $('.ful_'+i).addClass("change");  i--;
    }
});
```

css:

```
.scrol{
    width:50%;
    height:160px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x:hidden;
}
.ful{
    background:grey;
    margin-bottom:2px;
    border:1px solid;
}
.change{
    background:#fff;
}
.change1{
    background:#cdcdcd;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand how the image and description of the problem match up to what's in the fiddle?

Comment: did not understand the question... please elaborate.

Comment: Just use your `up` and `down` key. It highlights the nos. She wants to show the highlighted no, hidden inside `overflow`, may be by scrolling the it dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this goes in the direction you want?

```
var i = 1;

$(document).on('keydown', function (e) {

    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    } else if (e.keyCode == 40) {
        i++;
        if (i >= 11) i = 1;
        $('.ful').removeClass("change");
        $('.ful_' + i).addClass("change");
        $('.scrol').animate({scrollTop:$('.ful_' + i).offset().top},200);

    } else if (e.keyCode == 38) {
        i--;
        if (i <= 0) i = 10;
        $('.ful').removeClass("change");
        $('.ful_' + i).addClass("change");
        $('.scrol').animate({scrollTop:$('.ful_' + i).offset().top}, 200);

    }
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/a99He/2/